# using post method but undefined index

Tags: php

On first load page i get this undefined index error, i know why.. because post method never happened. So anyone can help me how to fix this simple?

```
        <form id="checkserver" method="POST">

<select class="btn2" name="server" onchange="$('#checkserver').submit();">
    <option value="all">Show all </option>
    <option value="Russia" <?=($_POST["server"] == 'Russia')?'selected':''?>>Russia</option>
    <option value="Europe" <?=($_POST["server"] == 'Europe')?'selected':''?>>Europe</option>
    <option value="Indonesia" <?=($_POST["server"] == 'Indonesia')?'selected':''?>>Indonesia</option>

    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: "The post method never happened"... so *why are you using `$_POST['server'] == 'Russia'` like it had?*

Comment: because i need to set selected dropdown...

Comment: Yes but the form hasn't submitted yet.

Comment: so how can i fix.. :)?

Comment: Check if it exists before trying to use it?

Comment: i already checked that..

Comment: No you didn't, because your code just says `$_POST['server'] == 'Russia'` without first checking if `$_POST['server']` exists!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here your work around code is.

```
<form id="checkserver" method="POST">

<select class="btn2" name="server" onchange="$('#checkserver').submit();">
    <option value="all">Show all </option>
    <option value="Russia" <?=(isset($_POST["server"]) && $_POST["server"] == 'Russia')?'selected':''?>>Russia</option>
    <option value="Europe" <?=(isset($_POST["server"]) && $_POST["server"] == 'Europe')?'selected':''?>>Europe</option>
    <option value="Indonesia" <?=(isset($_POST["server"]) && $_POST["server"] == 'Indonesia')?'selected':''?>>Indonesia</option>

    </select>
</form>
```

you have to check first for `$_POST["server"]` is set or not with 2 condition if isset and then check value. i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check first for check posted values,

ex.

```
<option value="Russia" <?php if($_POST["server"]){ ($_POST["server"] == 'Russia')?'selected':''; } ?>>Russia</option>
```

and also short handed tag is deprecated use `<?php echo`  instead of `<?=`

Answer (score 1):

You check like this.

```
<option value="Russia" <?= (($_POST["server"] && $_POST["server"] == 'Russia') ?'selected="selected"':'');?>>Russia</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must check if  exist post value:

```
isset($_POST['server'])
```

Answer (score -1):

When user open page in browser for first time, it will be requested with `GET` method. You will receive `POST` request only when user submits your form on already opened page.
So, you must check if request method is `POST` before using `$_POST` variable.

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //some code here
}
```